# validating html input in combination with asp.net server side controls

Tags: html, asp.net

```
<input id="TextBox1" name="nam"    type="text" tabindex="1" /> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="datepickereffective"  runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorForDateEffective" 
          runat="server"  ControlToValidate="datepickereffective"  
                    ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit"  OnClick="btnsubmit_onclick"/>
```

I want to check for the null values in the html input above .

**HAVE TRIED**:

```
Javascript onblur:dovalidation()
<script>
    do validation 
</script>
```

**ISSUE** : I want to validate input text without using `RUNAT=SERVER` because i am using jquery autocomplete and for some reason if i use runat="server" it is not picking the data. Also, my SUBMIT button is server side event because i am saving data from the text box . I cant even write a javascript function for my button click .

**WHAT I WANT**: Is there any property which forces the user to definetely click the html input so that i can handle the validation in client side . Because the javascript logic with onblur only works when i click it and dont slect anything. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CustomValidator in this case if you would like. Here's sample code:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="Cannot be empty" ValidationGroup="Html" ClientValidationFunction="dohtmlvalidation" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="Html"/>

//JS function
function dohtmlvalidation(sender, args) {
            if ($("#Text1").val() == "") {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
        }
```

[Demo](http://msonweb.azurewebsites.net/test.aspx): Check the Html Input Validation section at the bottom (ignore other test controls)

Comment: Your solution above is working but i also have required field validators along with custom validators .They are not showing required text.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="datepickereffective"  runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorForDateEffective" 
          runat="server"  ControlToValidate="datepickereffective"  
                    ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: Add ValidationGroup="Html" to your RequiredFieldValidator